# Asp.Net Identity Doesn't Remember Logged User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've an ASP.MVC application with Asp.Net Identity. I want to keep logged user's session for one year. I set cookie expire to for one year but the application ask user name and password after a few days. I don't want the application ask login information again.

What can i do?

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>
                        (TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
                            (manager, user) =>
                                user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager), id => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
                        ),
                    OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
                    {
                        ctx.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                        ctx.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: One year? That's just asking for security issues

Comment: Yes, i have an ecommerce app and i want to keep user's cart for a long time.

Comment: Then you don't store the aspnet user session. You store a cookie with the cart data

Comment: @Andrew what is another option without cookies. I think you mean it's not safe to keep cookies

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN What im trying to say is that you shouldn't be storing the users session data for a year as what happens if someone closes a window? Somebody else could come back, open that previously closed window and boom, you are logged in as that person in an ecommerce website.

Comment: @Andrew I don't think the OP is referring to **session state**, just the authentication ticket data. Storing cart-data in a cookie does not work because of limited storage space and lack of portability between clients.

Comment: he can clear cookie with logout. many sites works like that.

Comment: How will storing the cart data in a cookie not work? We don't know the full scope of OPs app but it could literally by a comma separated list of product IDs. And what do you mean by 'ticket data'?

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN If we're both talking about the aspnet user data what happens if the user doesnt log out and just closes the tab? My point still remains

Comment: yes you are right. what is the best cookıe time according to you @Andrew or what is the solution in there

Comment: i don't keep cart in a cookie. When a user come to my site i create a user  automatically and i login it. so i can keep cart if user's browser has authantication cookie.

Comment: If you need to store the shopping cart data for a year, you should store it in a database and use the Anonymous Identification Module as described [here](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). It doesn't make much sense to keep the user logged in all of the time just to keep track of a cart, nor is it very efficient to use session state for this purpose.